# Multiple lines of resultset into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query with a result set as follows

**EDIT: My bad, I pasted the wrong schema/resultset, the actual one looks like this**

`+-----------+------------+-----------+
| Record ID |    Date    | Note Type |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| XYZ       | 12/1/2014  | External  |
| XYZ       | 12/5/2014  | Internal  |
| XYZ       | 12/6/2014  | Internal  |
| ABC       | 11/10/2014 | External  |
| ABC       | 11/15/2014 | Internal  |
+-----------+------------+-----------+`

I want to get the output that answers the question

> **For a record when was the first Internal note and External note added?**

So in this case the output that I would want is as follows

`+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| Record ID | External Note | Internal Note |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| XYZ       | 12/1/2014     | 12/5/2014     |
| ABC       | 11/10/2014    | 11/15/2014    |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+`

I tried to achieve it using PIVOT but couldn't get the exact output and kinda stuck at this position, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select recordid, min([external note]) as [external note], min([internal note]) as [internal note]
from yourtable
group by recordid
```

Assuming your data follows the pattern you have shown in the sample, the above query can give you the minimum values without using `PIVOT`.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/YVUVS84289)

Based on your updated schema, you can still do it without pivot, like so:

```
;with cte_ext as
(select recordid as erid, min([date]) as minext
from yourtable
where [Note type] = 'External'
group by recordid),
cte_int as
(select recordid as irid, min([date]) as minint
from yourtable
where [Note type] = 'Internal'
group by recordid)

select e.erid as RecordID, e.minext as [External Date], i.minint as [Internal Date]
from cte_ext e
inner join cte_int i on e.erid = i.irid
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NWC72025)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, based on your simple solution I went ahead the checked the schema that I had posted which was wrong; sorry my bad. I have updated the schema, hope you can provide another solution to it.